# Python Matplotlib - fill_between remove white spaces between lines at top of yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) The colored patches are slightly angled vertically so there is white space at the top of the y axis, whereas the colors are nicely merged at the bottom of the yaxis. Anyone know how to prevent this/understand what is causing this?[image]

The plot is showing a 'weather window': when weather parameters are below a certain threshold the time period is 'operational' and at other times it is 'non operational'. The code to generate this plot is:

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3 * 3))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs.update(hspace=0.3)
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
df1.plot() # pandas DataSeries
ax0.set_xlabel('')
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
df2.plot() # pandas DataSeries
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax2.transData, ax2.transAxes)
ax2.plot(xtime, y, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5, lw = 0.01)
ax2.set_xlim(xtime[0], xtime[-1])
ax2.fill_between(xtime2, 0, 1, where = yop > 0, facecolor = 'green', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True, transform = trans)
# yop is numpy array of 0's and 1's
ax2.fill_between(xtime2, 0, 1, where = ynonop > 0, facecolor = 'red', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True, transform = trans)
# ynonop has 0's and 1's opposite to yop
```

The `interpolate = True` plays some role is removing the white spaces between points.

Here is simpler code to test the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0.0, 365, 1)
yop = np.random.randint(2, size=len(x))
ynonop = np.copy(yop)
# make 0's and 1's opposite to yop
ynonop[ynonop == 1] = 2
ynonop[ynonop == 0] = 1
ynonop[ynonop == 2] = 0
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.fill_between(x, 0, 1, where=yop > 0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5, interpolate = True, transform=trans)
ax.fill_between(x, 0, 1, where=ynonop > theta, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, interpolate = True, transform=trans)
plt.show()
# plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what is causing the white stripes, you may zoom into the plot.

[image]

Because `fill_between` fills between points that fulfil a certain condition, you get a sawtooth-like shape.

A possible solution might be to use a [`broken_barh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh) plot. To this end one would need to rearange the data into a 2columns format of (position, width).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

x = np.arange(0.0, 365, 1)
yop = np.random.randint(2, size=len(x))
ynonop = np.copy(yop)
# make 0's and 1's opposite to yop
ynonop[ynonop == 1] = 2
ynonop[ynonop == 0] = 1
ynonop[ynonop == 2] = 0

trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform() 
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.fill_between(x, 0, 1, where=yop > 0, facecolor='green', 
                alpha=0.5, interpolate = True, transform=trans)
ax.fill_between(x, 0, 1, where=ynonop > 0, facecolor='red', 
                alpha=0.5, interpolate = True, transform=trans)

trans2 = ax2.get_xaxis_transform()
xra = np.c_[x[:-1],np.diff(x)]
ax2.broken_barh(xra[yop[:-1] > 0,:], (0,1), 
                      facecolors='green', alpha=0.5, transform=trans2)

ax2.broken_barh(xra[ynonop[:-1] > 0,:], (0,1), 
                      facecolors='red', alpha=0.5, transform=trans2)  

ax.set_title("fill_between")
ax2.set_title("broken_barh")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `imshow`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0.0, 365, 1)
yop = np.random.randint(2, size=len(x))

trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
lc = mcolors.ListedColormap(['r', 'g'], name='RWG')
ax.imshow(yop.reshape(1, -1),
          extent=[0, len(yop), 0, 1],
          transform=trans,
          cmap=lc,
          norm=mcolors.NoNorm(), alpha=.5)

ax.set_aspect('auto')
# debugging plotting
ax.step(x, yop, '.', where='post', linestyle='none')
ax.set_ylim([-.1, 1.1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

By tweaking x values in `extent` you can control exactly where the pixels fall in dataspace.